# locate: ignore .git .svn and hidden folders in general when using wildcard

Tags: regex, locate

I try `locate -i -l 256 -r '*testhack*'` and I get all hidden files as results polluting my limited result list, things like `/home/kwaadpepper/testhack/TwitterReport/.git/objects/9a`.

I think that regex might solve my problem but how?
All I could managed to do was [this on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pR8uL7/1).

Answer (score 1):

I have found this `locate -i '*testhack*' | egrep -v "\/\." | head -n 256` but using only locate, although it seems faster than using regexes with locate.